# Best practice method for evaluating if a Django queryset object (or not) before slicing it?

Tags: python, django, object, slice, django-queryset

Depending on how my script is run I need to know if a variable produced at the end is a queryset object or not before I slice it.

I'm using:

```
if type(variable) == models.query.QuerySet:
    do_this
```

problem with evaluating the variable like this is that now when I slice it, it becomes a list which is not what I want because now I cannot invoke the `.values()` method.

Thanks in advance for any solutions :)

Comment: Why would a variable that is sometimes a QuerySet not always be a QuerySet? What else might it be?

Comment: In this case either i will end up with a queryset containing multiple objects or a single object in a list :) May seem a bit unorthodox but it's what I need right now.

Comment: Interesting - if it's only a temporary thing, I'd see what differences there are in the ``dir`` of the two types, and then use ``hasattr`` to distinguish between them, along with a giant comment explaining what's going on.

Comment: I will definitely give it a try :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
if isinstance(variable, QuerySet):
    do_this
```